# does each instance of class has thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have class A, and there will be multiple instance of the class at run time.

Does each instance create 5 threads with the below code?

```
public class A {

private void someMethod1(){

getPool();

}

private static ExecutorService getPool() {

        return (ExecutorService) new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 5,
                60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

    }
}
```

Requirement:

If there are 9 instances of class A, there will be 9*5=45 threads will be created? I am looking for a solution where the number of threads for example 50 cache able thread should be created only once and then any instance of that class should be reuse this pool of threads

Comment: And use ``ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is a singleton, create a new static class with a getter to get executor service,and call it anywhere you like:

```
public class MyExecutors {

  private static ExecutorService ex;

  public static synchronized ExecutorService getExecutor(){
    if(ex == null){
        ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 50, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
    }
    return ex;
  }
}
```

now just use `MyExecutors.getExecutor()` in all your instances. this will ensure the same executor instance for each class

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think the call should be MyExecutors.getExecutor(). Also, Can I use this code within my Class A instead of new class MyExecutors and add the private static ExecutorService ex in the class A globally?

Comment: you dont need to create an instance of `MyExecutors`, you can just use directly `MyExecutors.getExecutor()` from anywhere

Comment: Your example is not thread-safe: multiple threads could invoke the `getExecutor` method while `ex` is null, creating multiple `ThreadPoolExecutor`s.

Comment: thanks, my class A is not used by threads. But in the class A, I am going to create multiple thread and then add them to this ExecutorService Thread pool. So I think no need to use synchronized.

Comment: yeah you are right, if only 1 thread is going to use `MyExecutors.getExecutor()`, there is no need to synchronize